# Why javascript returns zero based day?

Tags: javascript

I know that javascript's `getMonth()` method returns the month as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year)

Is getDate() method also zero based date? (Not according to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate))

But when I pass string in YYYY-MM-DD format to date constructer, the getDate() returns zero based day.

```js
var d = new Date("2020-06-15");
console.log(getDatePartAsString(d));

function getDatePartAsString(d)
{
  if (!isValid(d)) {
      return "";
  }

  var dt = new Date(d);
  return dt.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
}

function isValid(d)
{
  return !isNaN(new Date(d).getTime());
}
```

**Update 1**
[image]

Comment: I get `Day 15` as an alert, as expected...

Comment: I cannot reproduce in any environment (various browsers, node). What platform/versions do you see this on?

Comment: I am getting 14. See update 1

Comment: im getting 14 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method will [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate#return_value):

> An integer number, between 1 and 31, representing the day of the month for the given date **according to local time**.

The problem isn't that the method is 0-indexed - the problem is that your local timezone is messing things up. Use `getUTCDate` instead so that the date number returned is in universal time (or otherwise corresponding to the timezone you passed into the Date constructor):

```js
var d = new Date("2020-06-15");
console.log("Day " + d.getUTCDate());
```

Comment: so basically by default Date constructor assumes the date string I am passing is in UTC and it converts that to my local timezone?

Comment: See specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). Yeah, if no timezone is in the passed date string, it'll be assumed to be UTC. So the internal date data stored for the Date instance constructed is for the first second of 2020-06-15 UTC. But if you retrieve data from that Date instance, certain methods will convert the result into local time first.